# Can Elastic net in R works with small data set

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a small data set with 33 rows & 7 columns,sorry I can't able to share my data as it's client data. I need to build a regression model using this data set. I thought to use elastic net. I don't have any prior experience of implementing elastic net in R. So I referred this link http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/37-model-selection-essentials-in-r/153-penalized-regression-essentials-ridge-lasso-elastic-net/#elastic-net & follow the steps.My elastic net code is given below

```
 model <- train(
 dataReg$sales ~., data = dataReg, method = "glmnet",
 trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
 tuneLength = 10
 )
```

But I'm getting the error message

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

Checked my data set dataReg$sales giving me 33 records & my data does not contain any missing value. Can you please guide me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Try using `model <- train(sales ~., data = dataReg, method = "glmnet", trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),  tuneLength = 10)`

Comment: 1. guessing elastic net is not necessary here. 2. Have you tried `sales ~ .` as you're train formula?

Comment: Yes,It's working after changing dataReg$sales to sales in formula. Thanks a lot. Can you please suggest me what's the problem with dataReg$sales?

Comment: The formula interface simply works different. You specify the formula without referencing the data.frame name directly. Instead, you have the `data = ` argument where you specify where the columns come from.